# Proving that a closed subset of $C[0,1]$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, equicontinuity

Let $C=C[0,1]$ be the space of all continuous functions on $[0,1].$
$$K_n(a)=\{x.\in C:|x_0|\leq 2^n,|x_t-x_s|\leq N(a)|t-s|^a \enspace\forall |t-s|\leq 2^{-n}\},$$

where $N(a)=\frac{2^{2a+1}}{2^a-1},\ t,s\in[0,1],\ n\geq0,$ and $a>0.$ Show that $K_n(a)$ are compact sets in $C$.

I am currently reading a book in Random Processes and this was given as one of the exercises. A theorem for compactness was given before this as:

> Let $K$ be a closed subset of $C$. It is compact if and only if the family of functions $x.\in K$ is uniformly bounded and equicontinuous, i.e. if and only if
> (i) there is a constant $N$ such that    $$\sup_{t}|x_t|\leq N \enspace\enspace \forall x.\in K$$
> (ii) for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|x_t-x_s|\leq\epsilon$ whenever $x.\in K$ and $|t-s|\leq\delta,\enspace t,s\in[0,1]$.

So I guess I first need to show that $K_n(a)$ are closed and then they are uniformly bounded and
equicontinuous.

Comment: Equicontinuity means that a collection of functions are continuous is a uniform sense, you need to look at the definition a little more closely. For closure, pick a sequence $x(k) \to x^*$ with $x(k) \in K_n(a)$ and show that $x^* \in K_n(a)$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for your comment. Great, I think I understood that. I also added my attempt to show closure and equicontinuity. Would be much appreciated if you could check my attempt and also if you could give me any hints to prove uniform boundedness.

Comment: Well, your approach is not correct in that it doesn't show equicontinuity and uniform boundedness. In order to conclude equicontinuity you need $\delta=\min(2^{-n}, \sqrt[a]{ \epsilon \over N(a)})$. For uniform boundedness note that $|x_t| \le 2^n + 2^n N(a) 2^{-an}$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Since the interval $[0,1]$ will be divided in to $2^n$ pieces, $|x_t| \leq \ 2^n + 2^n N(a)2^{-an}$. Great, thank you so much.

Comment: The theorem given in the book is called the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem. $K$ must also be closed to be compact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For closure, we want to show that every Cauchy sequence in $K_n(a)$ converges within the set.

Let $\{x_.(k)\}$ be a Cauchy sequence with $x_.(k)\in K_n(a)$, all $k$. Then by a known theorem, there exists a $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\{x_.(k)\}$ uniformly converges to $x.^*$ ( $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{t\in [0,1]}\{|x_t^*-x_t(k)|\}=0$), then $x.^*$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.

It remains to show that $x.^*$ satisfies the conditions to be in $K_n(a)$. Let $\epsilon > 0.$ Then
\begin{align} |x_t^*-x_s^*|=&|x_t^*-x_t(k)+x_t(k)-x_s(k)+x_s(k)-x_s^*|\\ \leq& |x_t^*-x_t(k)|+|x_t(k)-x_s(k)|+|x_s(k)-x_s^*|\\ \leq& \ \frac{\epsilon}{2}+N(a)|t-s|^a+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\ =& \ \epsilon+N(a)|t-s|^a,\end{align}

for all $t,s\in[0,1]$, such that $|t-s|\leq 2^{-n}.$ Hence, we have that $|x_t^*-x_s^*|\leq N(a)|t-s|^a \enspace \forall |t-s|\leq 2^{-n}.$

Morevover,
\begin{align} |x_0^*|=&|x_0^*-x_0(k)+x_0(k)| \\ \leq& |x_0^*-x_0(k)|+|x_0(k)| \\ \leq& \epsilon+2^n \end{align}

and hence $ x.^*\in K_n(a)$ and we have closure.

For uniform boundedness it is enough to notice $|x_t| \leq 2^n + 2^n N(a)2^{-an}$.

As for equicontinuity, let $\delta = \min(2^{-n},\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}a]{\frac{\epsilon}{N(a)}})$, since then $|x_t-x_s|\leq N(a)|t-s|^a \leq \epsilon$, whenever $|t-s|\leq \delta\implies |t-s|^a\leq\delta^a$.