# Is the set $L_{A,B}=\{f\in C([0,1]): |f(x)-f(y)|\leq A(x)|x-y|,\ |f(x)|\leq B(x),\ x,y\in [0,1]\}$ compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Givene $A,B\colon [0,1]\to [0,\infty)$ , is the set $L_{A,B}=\{f\in C([0,1]): |f(x)-f(y)|\leq A(x)|x-y|,\ |f(x)|\leq B(x),\ x,y\in [0,1]\}$ compact??
Note $(C([0,1]),d_\infty)$ when $d_\infty(f,g)=\sup \{|f(x)-g(x)|: x\in [0,1]\}$ Arzela Ascoli I guess?

Comment: You probably mean $|f(x)-f(y)|\le A(x)|x-y|$, right? Otherwise, what do you mean by $g$ there?

Comment: You might also get some ideas [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3699936/proving-that-a-closed-subset-of-c0-1-is-compact) together with Sellerie's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite right to assume that Arzela Ascoli would help you here. The statement goes as follows:

$L_{A,B}$ is compact, if it is closed and satisfies the two conditions of equicontinuity and pointwise boundedness.

Inside the definition of $L_{A,B}$ you are given two conditions - one similar to continuity, one similar to boundedness. You might want to try using the first to show equicontinuity and the second to show pointwise boundedness.

It remains to show that $L$ is closed. What would happen is you have a sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq L_{A,B}$ that converges? Can you show the fact that the limit function $f$ is also inside $L_{A,B}$? Can you show that $f$ satisfies both conditions?

Comment: so it is compact just i must to proove it?

Comment: I think that is not closed

Comment: I haven't written out a proof, but I am quite sure that it is compact, yes. What makes you think that it's not closed?

Comment: $A , B$ are functions (maybe not bounded). I solve it first easily for $Α,Β=const.$ 
Firstly, for closed I am not sure but,  I am sure that $L_{A,B}$ is not necessary bounded.